# Cannot find resource into ResourceDictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, resourcedictionary

I've got a common ResourceDictionary that use an Microsoft example for use a black ComboBox
[Microsoft Exemple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/combobox-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

In execution a exception was thrown :
Exception: Cannot find resource named 'NormalBorderBrush'. Resource names are case sensitive.

I just want to declare this combobox in my common ResourceDictionary xaml file

```
<!-- Combo box-->
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton" TargetType="ToggleButton">

<Border
      x:Name="Border" 
      Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
      CornerRadius="2"
      ...
      BorderBrush="{StaticResource NormalBorderBrush}"
      BorderThickness="1" />
...
<!-- Border Brushes -->
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="NormalBorderBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
        <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStopCollection>
                <GradientStop Color="#CCC" Offset="0.0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#444" Offset="1.0"/>
            </GradientStopCollection>
        </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
```

The NormalBorderBrush is declared in this same file !
What Am I doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance.
Eric

Comment: Make sure to declare the Brush before you use it. Maybe just move the Brushdeclaration above the ComboBox

Comment: Have you added `ResourceDictionary.xaml` file in  in `App.Xaml` ??

Comment: How did you declare NormalBorderBrush ? Show the code for that part also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order in which you define the resources matters.

The XAML compiler processes the file from top to bottom so to be able to reference `NormalBorderBrush` in the `ControlTemplate`, you need to define the brush *before* you define the template:

```
 <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="NormalBorderBrush" ... />

 <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton" ... />
```